# Why does drawImage() change the canvas outside the destination box?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) of `drawImage()`, I'm trying to draw to a specific part of a canvas.  However, areas outside of the destination box are being affected, namly having their alpha values zeroed.

I've [created a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axuh4903/10/) demonstrating the issue.

[image: canvas composition results]

I copied the canvas on the left (full yellow) to the canvas on the right and the drew the middle canvas to the center of that same canvas using "destination-atop".  You can see that it applied properly but at the same time cleared everything outside the draw area.  Same happens with "copy".  See the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axuh4903/10/) for details.

*Why does `drawImage()` affect pixels outside its destination?*

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the expected result. What alpha values are zeroed? The image is just smaller then the canvas?

Comment: Added expectation description.  See Fiddle for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me, the "destination box" (`dx`, `dy`, `dWidth`, `dHeight`) isn't actually a destination box.  It's more like a "center" and "scale" because drawing extends out of this box as though there were transparent source pixels being applied to that outside area.

The *fix* is to add a clipping rectangle before doing the drawing, as such:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
ctx.clip()
ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

The resulting [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhg9kd7q/) now does what I expected, applying the mask in the middle to the center of the solid-color image on the left to get the image on the right:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) of `destination-atop` is:

> **The existing canvas is only kept where it overlaps the new shape.** The new shape is drawn behind the canvas content.

You want to keep everything, use `source-over`:

> This is the default setting and draws new shapes on top of the existing canvas content.

```js
const SIZE = 150
const G = 63

let c1 = document.getElementById("c1")
c1.height = c1.width = SIZE
let ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d")
ctx1.fillStyle = "yellow"
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE)

let c2 = document.getElementById("c2")
c2.height = c2.width = SIZE
let ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d")
let g2= ctx2.createRadialGradient(
    SIZE / 2, SIZE / 2,
    SIZE / 10,
    SIZE / 2, SIZE / 2,
    SIZE / 2 - 1)
g2.addColorStop(0.00, `rgba(${G},${G},${G},0.000)`)
g2.addColorStop(0.25, `rgba(${G},${G},${G},0.500)`)
g2.addColorStop(0.50, `rgba(${G},${G},${G},0.750)`)
g2.addColorStop(0.75, `rgba(${G},${G},${G},0.875)`)
g2.addColorStop(1.00, `rgba(${G},${G},${G},1.000)`)
ctx2.fillStyle = g2
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE)

let c3 = document.getElementById("c3")
c3.height = c3.width = SIZE
let ctx3 = c3.getContext("2d")

ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx3.drawImage(c1, 0, 0, SIZE, SIZE)
ctx3.drawImage(c2, SIZE/4, SIZE/4, SIZE/2, SIZE/2)
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2"></canvas>
<canvas id="c3"></canvas>
```

Comment: `destination-over` doesn't apply anything.  `source-over` overwrites instead of applying.  I understand the operations.  The question is: _Why is it going outside the destination box?_  Is that just the nature of drawImage() that my specified destination isn't a hard limit?

Comment: The second image is smaller, `size/4` etc. So only were those images overlap is saved. So thats why you get the empty space.

Comment: So "destination" isn't actually a destination?  Instead, it's effectively a center-point and scale with the source extended to infinity with transparent pixels?